# Modify timestamp in google spreadsheet on the basis of changes in one cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have been trying to modify the timestamp when a specific cell is modified in google sheets. My end goal is that if the cell is edited to a value then the modified timestamp reflects and if contents of the cell is entirely deleted, then timestamp also deletes. My current script looks like this:

```
function onEdit()
{
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0,1);
      if((nextCell.getValue() == "" && r.value != "")  ||  (nextCell.getValue() != "" && r.value != "")) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      } else if(nextCell.getValue() != "" && r.value == "") { 
        nextCell.setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now this code is able to change the timestamp to current in case of any modification to cell, but if I entirely delete the content of the cell, timestamp does not delete, it again changes to the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit()
{
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) 
  {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var rvalue=r.getValue();
    if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) 
    {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0,1);
      if(rvalue != "")) 
      {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      } 
      else
      { 
        nextCell.setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also do it  with something like this:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet1") 
  {
    if(e.range.getColumn()==4) 
    {
      var nextCell = e.range.offset(0,1);
      if(e.value!="")) 
      {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      } 
      else
      { 
        nextCell.setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Although the latter is a little more difficult to debug.

> Note: there can only be one onEdit() in your project code.  If you have others then they all need to be combined into one with the appropriate conditional logic to keep them from interacting inappropriately.

Comment: Thanks Cooper. Your program perfectly worked. Is there also a way to record change in timestamps? I am trying to capture the dusration between 2 status of a task. To elaborate more, there will be multiple status of a task which will be recorded in a cell. As soon as someone changes the status by choosing from the drop down menu, timestamp is modified. I want to record the duration between these timestamps. P.S. I tried upvoting your answer but as i am new here, my reputation is less than 1 & my vote won't be publicly shown.

Comment: You could store the timestamp and maybe the row number  you already know the column numbers. Then store that information in a file or another spreadsheet and then you can come back later and measure the time differences between timestamps for any row. You may not want to do this during a simple trigger because I believe simple triggers have to end  in 30 seconds.