# Recording timestamp of change in status of a line item in google spreadsheet along with recording the change in status as well

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have been trying to capture the timestamp of changes to the status of each task. Tasks are mentioned in rows as task 1, task 2, & so on and their status is mentioned in col B after col A(Task name). Task status can be modified by users with whom spreadsheet is shared. There are 5 status of tasks: P,Q,R,S,T which can be achieved in any order (no definitive order of one status after the other). As soon as anyone modifies the status, I want to capture the timestamp & capture the status as well in next columns, so that all the changes to the status & timestamps are recorded in consecutive columns as Status 1 (P/Q/R/S/T) & timestamp. All the changes to the status of the task will be then recorded in corresponding columns.
I have already figured out the way to capture the change in status using this code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0,2);
      if((nextCell.getValue() == "" && r.value != "")) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      } else if(nextCell.getValue() != "" && r.value == "") { 
        nextCell.setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the link to my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kQzxu6i5uPYUVtFfMz9sKk6FiRKfiqzB92unBap9rF8/edit?usp=sharing

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You code **doesn't appear to make any attempt to address your question**. In fact your code looks almost exactly the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46991271/7215091).   We would appreciate it if you would try to solve your own problems and ask questions only if you run into problems.  Our goal is that at some point your experience will produce an ability to answer your own questions and that will take a little effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

This was the code from your previous question:

```
function onEdit()
{
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0,1);
      if((nextCell.getValue() == "" && r.value != "")  ||  (nextCell.getValue() != "" && r.value != "")) {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      } else if(nextCell.getValue() != "" && r.value == "") { 
        nextCell.setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> It looks very similar to your current question. Please try to answer your own question before asking for additional help.